# Inconsistent behavior of dojo date method

Tags: dojo

I have created a script to add 2 business days (weekdays) to one of the dates attribute. Here I have used dojo.date.add method as below

```
 var SDate=new Date(dojo.date.stamp.fromISOString(workItem.getValue("SDate19")));
 var tempDate = dojo.date.add(SDate, "weekday", 2);
```

It works fine and adding 2 days by excluding weekends until the SDate is any weekday other than Friday. If this SDate is Friday, then the result I'm getting is Sunday (ideally the calculated output should be Tuesday).

For example:

- If Input (SDate) is Aug 5, 2020, 1:00 AM, then Result (tempDate) is Aug 7, 2020, 1:00 AM
- If Input is Aug 6, 2020, 1:00 AM, then Result is Aug 10, 2020, 1:00 AM
- If Input is Aug 7, 2020, 1:00 AM, then Result is Aug 9, 2020, 1:00 AM --> Here result should be Aug 11, 2020, 1:00 AM

Initially, I thought that this issue is with Fridays only. But when I increase the No. of days from 2 to 3, then this issue appears for Thursday and Friday also.

And if I go on increasing this no. of days, then the issue is adding up to other weekdays as well.

Has anyone observed similar issue, or am I doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you did find a bug in dojo.date.add! It happens each time the interval is "weekdays" and adding the day of the week and the amount to add is 7 or greater.

Line 161 of dojo/date is: `var trgt = (strt + days)`, it should be: `var trgt = (strt + days) % 7;`

Your choice is either to not use dojo.date.add and write your own algorithm, or to have your own version of dojo.date, where you change line 161 as described above.